# php curl - browser vs the script

Tags: php, browser, curl, web-crawler

So I'm trying to crawl some webpages via CURL in PHP.

What I am experiencing is a different result when I view the page through web browsers vs php scripts.

Maybe they implemented some kind of feature to redirect pages when it is viewed via PHP scripts

any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean different result ?

Comment: Please give out more info. What are you trying to crawl exactly? Do you have any code, etc.

Comment: Inspect a request made by a browser and mimic that with curl.

Comment: so the script used to work fine but one day i'm getting different result

Comment: for example, the script is written to crawl the next page but now the "next page url" is always the first page

Comment: So your crawler worked fine up to one day. Did it occur to you that perhaps the owner of the website took measure against your crawling behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It's not unreasonable to imagine this actually happening.  The site owner might want to discourage page scraping. You can test this theory by passing a User Agent via cURL like this (this is the UserAgent for the iPhone):

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" http://www.apple.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have different results because maybe the page you loaded has some ajax content and it's loaded dynamically. cURL can only load static html and that's it. Anything after the intial load is lost. If you want a browser like experience web scrape consider [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)